# How to run a while loop in the background of my program?

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm making a Quiz for a school project and I want to start a timer at the start of the Quiz which will be stopped at the end and printed the time took for the player to complete the Quiz, I put the Timer that I created at the start but my program gets stuck at the 'While loop' and doesn't continue with the program.

Heres the beginning of my code:

```
import time

score = 0
lives = 3
o = 1
timer = 0

while o == 1:
  time.sleep(1)
  timer += 1
```

I add 1 to 'o' just before the Quiz ends so I can print out the time taken but I can get past the start

Comment: Please post your code and the error in your question. and avoid adding screen-shot of code instead post it in your question and please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Sorry, its my first time using this website

Comment: Its okay just edit your post and adds details to it to get better answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your While loop isnt comparing the value of 'o'. Use == not = and check.

Comment: You are not updating the value of 'o'. Hence, the condition is always true and the loop is infinite.